# How to use exe in SharePoint on itemAdded?

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, exe, gif

1. I have a need to convert any document gets uploaded to Image.
2. I downloaded the exe (with all the dlls) on my local machine (dont have to install)
3. export.exe sourcefile.doc destinationfile.gif  >> this syntax works from my local dos prompt.
4. How do I use the same syntax "export.exe exampledoc.doc exampledoc.gif" when an item is added to sharepoint doc library.
5. and Do I need to put the folder (where the exe and dlls are for this) in the sharepoint frontend server so it's accessible? If yes, where should this folder reside? Does the folder and files need sharepoint service account access?

I am totally new and I would really like if someone can shed some light on this (step by step if possible)?

Thanks
Justin...

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this from a SharePoint event handler, each WFE on the farm would need to have your conversion application available, your event handler code would need to place the uploaded file in a temporary location on disc, invoke the conversion application (look at the .NET [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for this), cancel the addition of the original, unconverted document, and add the output of your processed file to the library (ensure you use the DisableEventFiring() method of the event handler as to not have the event handler trigger itself during the addition of the new file), and then clean up after itself.

Having said that, this operation seems like something that you really wouldn't want to tax a web server getting any real traffic with doing in real time. You may want to look into batching the jobs to be done daily during traffic lulls by another system, or one dedicated resource on the farm.